# How to Swap Value and Store it Until Getting a Specific Value in a Vector?

Tags: matlab, swap

My MatLab program format is like below:

```
Value = x;

s = [vector];
```

... after some program ...

```
s1 = NewVector;

Value = NewValue;
```

Now, after each trial

1) I want to change the `Value` to `NewValue` and

2) Want to change `s` with `s1` until the first element of `s` becomes a desired value `z`

3) Also want to store all the `NewValue` in a vector at the same time

MatLab experts please help!

Answer (score 0):

More explanation required here...
I'll write what i've understood-

```
value=x;
s=[some-vector];
while s(1)~=z
  s=NewVector;
  value=[value NewValue];
end
```

This way, each iteration you read a new vector, and while the first elemnt is not `z` (z is a variable), the vector `value` getting more and more new values.